# ios installing firebase manually, getting error "firebase.h" file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am installing firebase for a react-native app, i have worked out the installation for android, it syncs and builds with no error. But I am having trouble with IOS adding firebase manually, And no I cannot use cococapods.

Here is the error that I am getting 
[image]

I have linked, cleaned, reopened and looked everywhere for a solution. I have followed the readme included in the zip to the dot and still getting error [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is common error message of react-native-firebase.
React-native link often fails because of various reasons.

So, you need to learn manual link of native libraries to not use cocoapod.
(cocoapod is GARBAGE!!!)
read this. It solve your problem.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

I recommend you to read step3 carefully.
try!

Comment: not working for me. In case of @react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging